# Programmatically importing module via importlib - __path__ not set?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I'm trying to import a sub-module programmatically. My file tree looks like this:

```
oopsd/__init__.py
oopsd/oopsd.py
oopsd/driver/__init__.py
oopsd/driver/optiups.py
```

The optiups.py simply prints "Hello World".

The oopsd.py looks like this:

```python
import importlib
importlib.import_module('oopsd.driver.optiups')
```

Now with this, I'm getting this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1521, in _find_and_load_unlocked
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "oopsd/oopsd.py", line 29, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "oopsd/oopsd.py", line 23, in main
    loaddriver()
  File "oopsd/oopsd.py", line 26, in loaddriver
    importlib.import_module('oopsd.driver.optiups')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1586, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1567, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1514, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 313, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1586, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1567, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1524, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'oopsd.driver'; oopsd is not a package
```

Does `__path__` even still exist in Python 3?

I also tried importing `.driver.optiups` instead, but this yields:

```
TypeError: relative imports require the 'package' argument
```

`__package__` seems unset, so I'm lost.

How do I do this the right way?

Comment: I think it is getting confused between the `oopsd` module, and `oopsd.py` file. Just try `importlib.import_module('.driver.optiups')`

Comment: In your tree you have `drivers`, in your code `driver` - could that be the problem?

Comment: @karthikr That requires the package argument, made this more clear in the original post now. Renaming oopsd.py to main.py gives me `ImportError: No module named 'oopsd'`

Comment: @mata That was a typo in the post - corrected now

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is an old question, but since it was bumped, the other answer is totally wrong, and this is a common problem:

You're probably doing this.

```
python oopsd/oopsd.py
```

Don't do this.  :)

Specifically, **NEVER** try to directly run a file that's part of a parent package.  When you run `python FILENAME`, Python adds the file's *containing directory* to `sys.path`, and DOESN'T add the current directory.  So you have `oopsd/` in your path, and every module in `oopsd/` just became a top-level module.  Python has no way of even knowing that any of them are supposed to have an `oopsd.` prefix, because the parent directory doesn't exist anywhere in `sys.path`.

If you want to execute a module directly, do this:

```
python -m oopsd.oopsd
```

This puts the *current directory* in `sys.path` and ensures that imports of your source tree work as you'd expect them to.

Alex Z's answer is wrong because it doesn't actually fix this problem, and it's **not a relative import** — implicit relative imports no longer exist in Python 3.

Comment: I also learned more about modules and packages since asking the question, and completely forgot about that project in the meantime :D After using -m and adjusting some import so they actually import with the full dotted path, everything works!

Answer (score -2):

This works for me (relative path to driver):

```
import importlib
importlib.import_module('driver.optiups')
```

(karthikr in comments was close, but you don't seem to need the leading `.`)